# TypeError: execute expected at most 2 arguments, got 5

Tags: python, sqlite

i dont understand what this error means could anyone please help me i will attach the piece of code down below

```
else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Users' (Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", str(Firstname.get()), str(Lastname.get()), str(Username.get()), str(Password.get(),))
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter values need to be in a single argument, not separate arguments.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Users' (Firstname, Lastname, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    (Firstname.get(), Lastname.get(), Username.get(), Password.get()))
```

There's also no need to call `str()`, as `Entry.get()` returns a string.